# Как задать определённое сообщение в переменную?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Задать сообщение в переменную по id,чтоб далее его,например удалить

```
if(mess.content.startsWith('!del'));             
var trigger_mess = trigger_mess.delete();
```

Comment: Что такое в вашем коде mess? Опять же, id - это идентификатор какого-то элемента на веб-странице или имелось в виду что-то иное?